# Express-validator 7.0.1 isDate() always return false

Tags: node.js, express-validator

The following code works for express-validator 6.14.2.

```
const checkDate = check("date").isDate();

// simplified but you get the idea, 
app.post(
    "/path1",
    [checkDate],
    async (req, res) => {
        ... process the req ...
    }
);
```

For my test, i have req.body = { date: "2021-02-12", ... }

It used to pass this date check on v6.14.2, but starts failing on v7.0.1.
If i comment out this checkDate, then test is passing again.

I checked the changeLog but didn't see anything.
Anyone knows why it's not working ? Thx !

Answer (score 0):

Do not believe this is express-validator issue, should be related to yarn v1 or v3. Packages are messed up with yarn, e.g. https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/22431